# Facebook SDK 3.0 Auto Login

Tags: ios, facebook, session, authentication

I'm new to facebook SDK 3.0 IOS

Is there any way to auto - login to facebook SDK 3.0?

My specification is, we can integrate facebook to our application member ID (it's like instagram where we can integrate facebook to our ID)

So, if the member logging out, facebook integration will be logged out, and when the member logging in, facebook will auto login.

Is there anyway to do this? Like storing access token to server maybe?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=THE_ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_USER

and only one time login, sesión not expire.

Excuse my english